# Can I get 50 questions on my front page, please?

Tags: feature-request, filtering, pagination

Seriously... some days I only have fourty, some days twenty.  Some times it dips down to ten or so.  Yeah, I've got a butt-ton of filters, but so what?  Does that make me a bad person?

A possible workaround may be to increase the number of questions we can have on the front page, like 100 or 200 or something.

Comment: "Does that make me a bad person?" yes.

Comment: That cuts me to the core.  You are no longer my mancrush.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ - Do you still have a lot of ignored tags as a mod?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Aw hell yeah.  Have you seen how many questions come through this town?  Between clearing flags and my two RSS feeds (MVVM and WF4) my free time is eaten all up.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ - Ah, that makes sense. As a mod on a 2.0 site, I read every question that comes through, and it would seem inappropriate for me to filter tags out.  You get to just look at the flags on SO.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: We have over 300 flags in the queue right now.  Been averaging around 400 the past week, over 1.1k flags handled over the past 24 hours (if the stats page is to be believed!).  There just isn't enough time for a volunteer to try and handle a hundred or so flags a day and still read all posts.  I have my two feeds, and I try to keep the questions coming through them in good shape.  I don't know if other mods do the same.

Comment: We have just under 1.1 **hundred** flags handled in the past 25 **days**, if the flags page is to be believed. Different worlds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and also get rid of the annoying lag between the moment a page finishes to load and when the filtered-out message are removed.

A bunch of features on SO seem to be implemented like this. The filters, the Inbox icon and the orange toolbar. A bit annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a screenshot of a particularly inopportune moment on the 'newest' page.

Sorry for the length, but this is the resized version.  The [larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehUaV.png) is how it looks for me *all the time*.  You just have to scroll through it once.

I'll admit that this is a particularly bad case, there are usually 5-10 questions, but fewer isn't that uncommon)  There are 375 pixels of questions, and 3492 pixels of white, blank, useless, empty space.

[image]

It seems that the [default "Interesting" page] works better, but this is simply ridiculous.

Comment: Man, you hate you some tags.

Comment: Use wildcards to ignore. Adding `sql*` gets rid of `sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008,...` and `*sql*` also gets rid of `mysql, tsql,...`

Comment: @yoda - Yeah, I'm going through there to clean them.  Sathya told me about the wildcards [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110224/sort-favourite-tags-on-the-sidebar-in-alphabetical-order/110262#110262); I think I must have made a misspelling in `visual-studio*` when I first experimented to see if wildcards worked.  **However,** a reduced tag set using wildcards doesn't mitigate the fact that there are 3 questions (now likely to be fewer, because wildcards will catch stuff I missed) on my front page.

Answer (score 2):

Would be helpful, currently all questions are loaded and then irrelevant ones are hidden with javascript post-load.

This could decrease unnecessary bandwidth use but would increase server side processing. Not exactly sure which is worse.