# Can blocked questions not count in the "x questions per page" option?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, blocked-tags

If I have a bunch of blocked tags, it seems those questions still count for the amount of questions per page even though I never see them. Can this be fixed?

Comment: this is a client-side filter.  see similar postslike  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/hide-ignored-tags-should-retrieve-more-questions-to-fill-up-the-page

Comment: But the server remembers your choice of tags and could filter those out for you...

Comment: and more specifically:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/questions-per-page-not-honored-when-using-ignored-tags

Comment: Two more very similar requests: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/can-i-get-50-questions-on-my-front-page-please, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13122/please-can-we-have-an-extra-button-100-for-more-questions-per-page