# Sort Favourite Tags on the sidebar in alphabetical order

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching

I think it would be nice to display tags in alphabetical order. Currently, tags are displayed in order of creation.

As a workaround, I remove, and then add the tags, which is a bit dumb, but I like 'em in alphabetical order.

It's probably pretty trivial to implement, and nice to have!

Comment: `tags are displayed in order of creation.` -> which page are you referring to?

Comment: Any Stack Exchange site; e.g. I have tags "cakephp", "javascript" in my list of favourite tags. If I were to add "codeigniter", the tag is appended to the list; i.e. "cakephp", "javascript", "codeigniter" instead of (my preference) "cakephp", "codeigniter", "javascript".

Comment: Ok, could you mention why it's nice to have? I'm not entirely sure I understand what's the net gain in having it arranged in asc. order

Comment: Well, I would like it in alphabetical order, and in order for me to see that, I often remove all my tags, and then re-add 'em in alphabetical order.

Comment: Saying that it would be nice to have since you want it is a bit too little. What is the real benefit from changing it?

Comment: Well, maybe the only beneficiary might be me, AFAIK. So I wanted to know if there were any other users along this line. Maybe not.

Comment: @slhck  - What's the real benefit for having them in order of creation?

Comment: @Sathya - I've posted an explanation as an answer below. How many tags do you have in your lists?

Comment: @WayneKhan - Nope, also want this! Though I don't take the time to remove and re-add the tags.

Comment: @KevinVermeer It's not about *not* wanting it too, but in order to get a feature request through you should tell people why it's better.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I can understand - mine's manageable http://i.imgur.com/5Nfzh.png

Comment: I'm so so glad I'm not the only one to feel this way. Kevin's might be the best idea, having an switch case for creation time or alphabetical order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wholeheartedly support this suggestion!  It's easy enough to re-order your ignored and favorite tags if you've only got a few, but I'm neither a web developer, nor an applications developer.  There's so much [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) stuff on SO that it's hard to find the stuff I'm interested in if I don't filter it out.  My preferences look like this:

[image]

Quick - Am I ignoring the [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight) tag or not?  You'll see [silverlight-3.0](/questions/tagged/silverlight-3.0) and [silverlight-4.0](/questions/tagged/silverlight-4.0) on the left below the [actionscript](/questions/tagged/actionscript) and [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tags, but [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight) isn't there.  If I suddenly see a [silverlight-5.0](/questions/tagged/silverlight-5.0) question (does that exist yet?) I'm going to also want to ignore [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight) and all its associated versions.  The current setup makes it difficult to scan, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> works but my eyes could do it quickly if the list was alphabetized. (Quicker on the prefs page at least; this list is  about 2 1/2 times the height of my browser when it's next to the questions feed, so <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> is quicker than scrolling).

Let's ask "Why shouldn't it be sorted alphabetically?" instead of asking why it should be.  For my use case, I have no need to sort by time.  I can't conceive of a use case that would be.

Comment: Related: [Can I get 50 questions on my front page, please?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/can-i-get-50-questions-on-my-front-page-please) and its associated troubles are magnified with lots of ignored tags.

Comment: Note: This post reminded me to go work on this again.  I went to the front page, scrolled down until I could see the "Add" box, and added ignored tags until I didn't see anything I didn't want to see anymore.  It's another 2 or 3 lines longer now.

Comment: btw - you can use wildcards http://i.imgur.com/5Nfzh.png

Comment: @Sathya - Great comment, thanks for that.  I tried it once, but I must have misspelled the tag or something because it didn't work, and I used a big list instead.  However, I'll still have a big list even with wildcards.

Comment: Agreed.  I have 49 favorite tags on SO (and no ignored tags).  I'd at least like the *option* of displaying them alphabetically, in case some users prefer creation order.

Answer (score 4):

<s>You can easily do this by writing a UserScript.</s> Actually, I decided to just go ahead and write one.

Here it is: http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/reorder_tags.user.js

If you are using Chrome, just click the link above. If you are using Firefox, make sure you have the GreaseMonkey extension installed. If you are using anything else, please [look at this page for directions](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

Once the script is installed, visit any Stack Exchange site and your list of favorite and ignored tags will be listed in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Alphabetized tags have now been implemented.

[According to Shog9 on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368044/3357935), this was implemented as part an upcoming redesign for tag watching as part of Teams.

> We're currently working on porting the redesigned tag-watching features that we've built for Teams back into the public Q&A sites. This redesign features a number of new features and a streamlined UI (no more hidden "ignore" function, no more having to visit your profile page to change how ignored tags work!). The public version of this UI hasn't changed yet (beyond the sorting), but the plumbing is in place now.

So, I suppose this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), even if it wasn't intentional.

(Related: *[My favorite tags are alphabetized now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310294/351462)*)

Comment: To be clear, the *alphabetization* was intentional; the previous behavior was also intentional, but... mostly just convenient.