# Can we please have the system automatically alphabetize tags in our sidebars?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort Favourite Tags on the sidebar in alphabetical order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110224/sort-favourite-tags-on-the-sidebar-in-alphabetical-order)

#### Background

This question is related to [Ability to sort/reorder interesting/ignored tags in sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar), but the feature request in the other post was a lot more complex and sweeping. My request is a lot narrower in scope, and (IMHO) much more actionable since it just a record sort instead of a radical UI redesign.

The core issue for me is that, with a LOT of tags, it is very hard to find the ones I'm looking for because they are not sorted alphabetically. From a UI perspective, it's not very usable without breaking flow.

#### Feature Request

Can we please have the system automatically alphabetize tags in our sidebars?

Comment: This ended up getting closed while I was in the middle of writing an answer - so I just [answered the original question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135281/142114).

Comment: @random Is this really an exact duplicate? I'm not asking "How can a user do this himself?" I'm asking "Can we have the *system* present tags in alphabetical order?" I'd be glad to edit the title if that's enough of a differentiator for you to reopen the question.